# Knative: update image of a service in a CI autodeploy pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, knative, container-image

I recently converted my kubernetes deployment service to a knative serverless application. I am looking for a way how to update the image of a container the the knative app from a CI/CD pipeline without using yml file (CI pipeline doesn't have access to the yaml config used to deploy the file). Previously, I was using `kubectl set image` command to update the image from CI to the latest version for a deployment but it does not appear to work for a knative service, e.g. the command I tried is:
`kubectl set image ksvc/hello-world hello-world=some-new-image --record`

Is there a way to update the image of a knative app using a kubectl command without having access to the original yaml config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `kn` CLI:

https://github.com/knative/client/blob/master/docs/cmd/kn_service_update.md

```
  kn service update hello-world --image some-new-image
```

This would create a new revision for the Knative service though.
You can clean up old revisions with `kn`.

Get `kn` here: https://knative.dev/docs/install/install-kn/